AQEShuffleRead in Spark Creating few partitions though advisoryPartitionSizeInBytes and initialPartitionNum is provided
I have added the spark.sql.adaptive.advisoryPartitionSizeInBytes=268435456  and spark.sql.adaptive.enabled=true. However my data size for each partition is more than 256 mb. I see the Dag where the AQEShuffleRead creates less partition then spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.initialPartitionNum.
Question: I think enabling AQE will reduce the partition when ever there smaller partitions size.Here the data size per partition is quite high. Can any one throw some light on this.

Spark-Submit commnd:
spark-submit --conf spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes=268435456 \
--master yarn --deploy-mode cluster  --conf spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1 \
--conf spark.sql.hive.metastorePartitionPruning=false \
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.enabled=true --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false \
--conf spark.sql.parquet.filterPushdown=true \
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.enabled=true \
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.advisoryPartitionSizeInBytes=268435456 \
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.optimizeSkewsInRebalancePartitions.enabled=true \
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.rebalancePartitionsSmallPartitionFactor=.5 \
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.parallelismFirst=false \
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.initialPartitionNum=30000 \


The AQE (Adaptive Query Executor) will set the best shuffle partition number for the next stage, as well as combining or coalescing small partitions automatically at execution time to achieve the best data distribution as possible across the tasks and consequently avoid overhead with small files.
Therefore by enabling the following spark conf spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.enabled AQE will still merge smaller partitions into larger ones because it might still have room for improvement even if they are already near the advisory size provided by spark.sql.adaptive.advisoryPartitionSizeInBytes in order to balance the workload and prevent at any cost small files problem. If you wanna fully fine tuning your workload manually, you may consider deactivating the coalescePartitions capability, specially because sometimes AQE make things a bit more complex than expected for really complex execution plans. However in most cases it's always a good idea have AQE enabled.
